# How to Synchronize Session / Security between ASP.NET and Tomcat?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, session, tomcat

I have an Asp.NET 3.5 application with security/authentication.  I have a second application (built using GWT and running on Windows Tomcat) running on a different machine.

I need to make the second application available to the user via a link generated from the .NET application.  This part is easy, I have constructed the link in the asp.net page and the user can click on it to start working in the GWT/Tomcat session.

My question is this...

How do I set it up so that the Tomcat/GWT application is **Only Accessible via the link** in my asp.NET application?

I don't want the user to be able to copy the link from my asp.net page and then share that with someone else who is not authenticated within my asp.net application.

Comment: why not consider a truely webbased Single Sign On solution instead of security through obscurity?

Comment: +1 for Nice use of content-less buzz-words; If I had the ability to change any of the environment that I am working in I would.  Comments like these are singularly unhelpful in that they neglect to address the question... at all.

-1 for an inappropriate assessment of my problem.  I'm not looking for security through obscurity, I'm looking for a way to synchronize the security I already have in place on the .NET side with some mechanism on the tomcat side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tomcat application will be passed a cookie that is the .NET authentication token iff the client has logged in to your .net application.

Your tomcat application can get this cookie from the request headers, and compose another request with this cookie to check with your .net server and see if the cookie (token) is valid.

Comment: This sounds EXACTLY like what I need.  Any refs I can give the guys (3rd party) who are developing the tomcat app?

Comment: ... iff the client has logged in to your .net application **and** both the applications are served from the exact same domain. This necessarily implies you have a proxy server sitting ahead of the IIS and Tomcat servers, giving the browser the impression that both applications are on the same domain.